# Xcode preview changing even after pinning it

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I have the Canvas preview open and auto-refreshing the view that I am working on.

When I click on the pin in the bottom left corner, it fills with blue, giving me the impression that it's been pinned. But, when I navigate to a different view, that view is then previewed and the pin in the bottom left is still highlighted blue.

I'm currently worthing within Xcode 11.5.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue on the, as of writing, latest Xcode 12.4. After messing around with it, I've been able to figure it out; the trick is to make sure that at the time of pinning, the live preview is **off**. Then pin, change previews, and voila.